# Trying to run a binary in the smallest possible container

Tags: docker, dockerfile

The Dockerfile:

```
FROM scratch
COPY hello /app/hello
ENTRYPOINT ["/app/hello","-g","OMGITWORKS!"]
```

where `hello` is a copy of `/usr/bin/hello`. The commands:

```
docker build -t hello .
docker run hello
```

Using `FROM scratch` or `FROM alpine` I get:

```
standard_init_linux.go:185: exec user process caused "no such file or directory"
```

`docker inspect` seems to imply that the container runs the binary without a shell:

```
"Path": "/app/hello",
"Args": [
    "-g",
    "OMGITWORKS!"
],
```

and

```
"Entrypoint": [
    "/app/hello",
    "-g",
    "OMGITWORKS!"
],
```

But, surprise, with `FROM python:3.4`:

```
OMGITWORKS!
```

Probing the innards of the alpine-based container shows:

```
/ # ls -al /app/hello
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root         23112 Mar 21 15:25 /app/hello
```

So, I don't really understand what is going on. What is the magic in the python:3.4 image?

Comment: I know alpine doesn't load a bash shell

Comment: have you tried: FROM python:3.4-alpine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> exec user process caused "no such file or directory"

This is often cause for confusion as it's a bit misleading if, like in your case, the binary actually exists. Usually this indicates a non-static binary that can't find it's libraries it is linked against, most likely glibc, but depends on the app obviously. Running `ldd /app/hello` should give you a list of linked libraries.

> What is the magic in the python:3.4 image?

The "magic" is that `python:3.4` is based on [glibc](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/), while `alpine` is based on [musl](https://www.musl-libc.org/). Binaries linked against either are not compatible with the other. You have a few options:

1. For a quick test use `FROM alpine-glibc`, if it works you know for sure it is the missing glibc, else there might be more missing -> `ldd` and install any missing libraries in your `Dockerfile`
2. Build your binary in a musl container so it's linked against the correct standard lib if you want to use `FROM alpine`
3. Build a completely static binary and use any image, even `scratch`

The recently added Docker [multistage](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/) feature comes in handy for the last two options.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to @ErikDannenberg's answer:

[This blog post](http://blog.oddbit.com/2015/02/05/creating-minimal-docker-images/) describes in detail how one can use `ldd` and `objdump` to figure out all the dependencies and how to add them to the docker image.

And it also points to the [`dockerize` tool](https://github.com/larsks/dockerize) which does that automatically.